# First 5 elements of a list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I was wondering, if I was given a list such as:

```
 (list 3 6 9 2 1 0 5 9)
```

and I wanted to produce only the first 5. i.e.: I want to produce:

```
 (list 3 6 9 2 1)
```

How could I go about doing this. By the way, recursion is not allowed, and the language is [intermediate student](http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate.html). Thanks :)

Comment: Is it `Intermediate Student with lambda` or without?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because you are asking us to do your homework, and it's not even interesting homework.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a lis like `(1 2 3 4)` is a chain of pairs `(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . ()))))`. You cannot reuse the pairs since you need the 5th pair to point to `()` (null) instead of the rest of the pair chain. The only way to do this is to make a new `pair` for each element you'd like by using the same `car` elements in each.

```
(define (take lst cnt)
  (if (zero? cnt)               ; if you ask for zero element
      '()                       ; then return empty list
      (cons (car lst)           ; else make a pair with first element
            (take (cdr lst)     ; and result from take with the rest of the list
                  (- cnt 1))))) ; with one less element than you originally asked for
```

Comment: This is how sane code would look, but the author specifies "recursion is not allowed". But, no, I don't think it's possible to satisfy that constraint either. Have a vote up since ignoring the recursion comment probably makes more sense than my answer, which ignores good programming sense (as I'd assumed it was a teaching exercise).

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, in addition to `car` and `cdr`, Scheme supplies `caar`, `caaar`, `caaaar` and the equivalent repeated `d`s and the various combinations and permutations. So one solution would be:

```
(define x (list 3 6 9 2 1 0 5 9))
(list (car x) (cadr x) (caddr x) (cadddr x) (car (cddddr x)))
```

(and I'm sure that's why you were asked for the first five; there's no `cdddddr` — the teaching point was likely the permitted repetition of `d`s and `a`s and the limit to which you can go with those)

Comment: There's also `first`, `second`, `third`, `fourth`, `fifth`, etc.

Comment: That is a solution, but I need the solution to work for any length of list and any number of elements I want to keep.

Comment: @IanMurphy you're asking us to do a loop, in Scheme... without recursion? Recursion is how loops are formed in Scheme.

Comment: For example, the same function must be able to take 

     (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)

and produce (list 1 2) if I tell it to

Comment: methinks you're misunderstanding the assignment. Maybe ask your fellow students?

Comment: Aren't there also `cadr`, `caddr`, `cadddr`, etc.?

Comment: @dfeuer the manual says yes: http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_8.html#IDX326 which had escaped my memory. I guess I'll update the answer even though it's still unclear to me what the original asker expects.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you would want to do this, but one way to avoid recursion is to unroll the loop:

```
(define (take1 xs) (cons (car xs) '()))
(define (take2 xs)
   (cons (car xs) (take1 (cdr xs))))
(define (take3 xs)
   (cons (car xs) (take2 (cdr xs))))
(define (take4 xs)
   (cons (car xs) (take3 (cdr xs))))
(define (take5 xs)
   (cons (car xs) (take4 (cdr xs))))
```